# Find six triples of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ such that in $ \frac{9}{a} + \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{9} = c$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $a, b$ and $c$ in the following equation such that

> Find six triples of positive integers (a, b, c) such that

$$  \frac{9}{a} + \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{9} = c$$

I have tried various techniques with out any success.

Comment: a,b,c can be any real number?

Comment: @vadim123 found the original source it should be fixed http://ssma.publishpath.com/Websites/ssma/images/Problems%20Section/December-2007.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find $(9,9,3), (2,12,6), (162,4,41), (405,25,19), (18,36,5), (54,12,6)$ just by brute force search.  I made an Excel sheet with $a$ down the first column, $b$ across the top row, computed the LHS and scanned for integers.  Copy down/copy right is your friend.

Added:  extending the search with a Python program, I also find $(14,588,66), (378,588,66)$

Comment: This is not expected.

Comment: I checked the last two with Alpha, which does exact rational math and agrees.  Given the source of the problem, I suspect one was supposed to have a non-computer approach.  There are no more with both $a,b \lt 10,000$

Answer (score 1):

it is true? 
$$(9,9,3)$$
Why not?

Comment: There are six triples that is the most obvious one yes.